# Installing a local package on Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to run a local package on Meteor.

I've got a correct package.js, have a smart.json, and it's inside my /packages directory in my Meteor project. The smart.json at my project looks like this:

```
{ 
    "packages": {
        "router": {},
        "userErrors": {
            "path": "/home/user/Documents/project/packages/userErrors" 
        }
    }
}
```

And I am using api.add_files and all correctly. The code runs fine when I take it out of the packages folder. Is there something I'm missing in order to make this package run? I'm running Meteor with the `mrt` command.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

try to put your files in the 'packages' directory of your app and execute :
meteor add [package-name]

Comment: Nice! The distinction between `mrt` and `meteor` is what kept throwing me off.

Comment: in fact mrt is [meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite) , a separate tool from meteor for version and package management.

Comment: It's interesting that the package system between meteor and mrt seems to be completely independent. Seems like there is redundancy no?

Comment: No there's no redundancy at all. Meteor let you manage officials package and locals packages you want to include manually, while meteorite use [atmosphere](https://atmosphere.meteor.com), which is a index of smart packages, created by the community.

Comment: Can someone clarify Where is the 'packages' directory located?? There seem to be four different candidates: ./.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/packages
./.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages
./.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages
./.meteor/local/build/programs/ctl/packages

Comment: None of the directorys you mention. You're not suppose to dig .meteor, this is where meteor store his stuff.
After have create your project ( meteor create my-project-name ), you should have a directory my-project-name.
The package directory is my-project-name/package

Answer (score 31):

Meteor from 0.9 does not have a "packages" directory by default, but will still use it for local packages. Create it if it doesn't exist.

```
cd <your-app>
mkdir packages
```

Your locally developed package needs to be inside this folder. Of course you can simply create a symbolic link. You can do this yourself with `ln -s` or use the feature of mrt:

```
mrt link-package /path/to/<your-package>
```

Please note, if you provide a relative path, this must be relative to the packages directory, not relative to your current location. So you might want to `cd` into the packages directory first to avoid confusion.

Finally add the package:

```
meteor add <your-package>
```

IMPORTANT: `<your-package>` needs to be the name of the description inside your `package.js`. The name of the folder/symlink is not relevant for this procedure.

```
Package.describe({
  name: "<your-package>"
});
```

If your local package has the same name as a package registered online, your local version will be used.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer is not as good as this one: https://dweldon.silvrback.com/local-packages

Answer (score 2):

Machine: OSX 10.10.4, Meteor 1.1.0.3, Bash 3.2.57(1)-release

1.Create local meteor packages dir and example package.

```
mkdir ~/.meteor_local_packages && cd $_ && meteor create --package user:package-name
```

2. Check version set to 0.0.1 at least

```
cat ~/.meteor_local_packages/package-name/package.js | grep version:
```

3.Point to meteor local packages

```
echo 'export PACKAGE_DIRS=~/.meteor_local_packages' >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile
```

4.Go to your meteor project dir

```
meteor add user:package-name
```

5.Show list

```
meteor list | grep user:package-name
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to follow these two steps:

1. `meteor create <package-name>` (This will create the package inside of your `packages` folder).
2. `meteor add <package-name>` (This will add the reference of your new package to your `/.meteor/packages` folder).

And then you can start working on your new meteor package.

Comment: According to official docs, packages are created with `meteor create --package <package-name>` https://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteorcreate

Answer (score 1):

Just like Xiv suggested,
Copy the package into packages folder (create "packages" folder inside main directory of your application).
Do

```
meteor add <package name>
```

( remember: package name is not the folder name it is specified in package.js inside the package)