# Issue while trying to upload file to S3 using http.put

Tags: file-upload, meteor, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload file to S3 directly from client. Here is my code to upload:

```
var s3Options={
       "params":{
                    "key":options.folder+'/'+recordId+extn,
                    'AWSAccessKeyId':policy.s3Key,
                    'acl':'private',
                    'policy':policy.s3PolicyBase64,
                    'signature':policy.s3Signature,
                    'Content-Type':fileData.type,
                    'Content-Length': fileData.size,
                    'file':fileData,
                    "enctype":"multipart/form-data",
                }
            }
```

Now I am trying to upload a image and file gets uploaded but instead of image, the content-type in request is binary/octet-stream and when I access the file in app, it shows me message in console:
    Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type binary/octet-stream:

Here is how I am uploading the file:
    HTTP.put('https://'+process.env.S3_BUCKET+'.s3.amazonaws.com/'+options.folder+'/'+recordId+extn ,s3Options,function(error,result){
                    console.log("put file", error, result)
    }

Now lets say my file's url is https://myBucket.s3.amazonaws.com/User/avatar/profile.png. Here is the content of file:

This is the put request sent to upload the file:

```
Remote Address:xxxxx
Request URL:https://myBucket.s3.amazonaws.com/User/avatar/profile.png
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Host:myBucket.s3.amazonaws.com
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/avatar
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2)     AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:HEAD, GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:ETag, x-amz-meta-custom-header
Content-Length:0
Date:Wed, 25 Feb 2015 10:42:51 GMT
ETag:"xxxxxxxxx"
Server:AmazonS3
Vary:Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
x-amz-id-2:yyyyyyyyyyyy
x-amz-request-id:DDDDDDDDDDD
```

I have verified the content-type set in s3Options and it is image/png.

Comment: any reason not to use https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot this package?

Comment: Since this is an important utility, I want to build this functionality in the application since sometimes packages are not maintained/updated with the upcoming meteor versions.

Comment: Okay, small suggestion, If this package fulfill all the requirements, why don't you keep the code in your local system and use that code and update the package code according to your requirements and for future meteor release updates, If you want to do like that, here is how to add local packages in meteor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328000/installing-a-local-package-on-meteor

Comment: I cannot do that now. My functionality is already complete but this small issue. If its fixed, my local package would be good enough.