# Dependency management in MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am new to Meteor and I am wondering what is the best way to handle dependency management. Up until now, everything Node related I have done has pulled in dependencies with the `require` method.

```
var myCoolModule = require("myCoolModule");

myCoolModule.doAwesomeThing();
```

Based on the information I could find, this is not the correct approach in Meteor. However, I did not see any clear cut alternatives.

I am referring to both my own modules I may write within my own app and 3rd party modules I might want to pull in from NPM. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your own modules, you will set up a local package with a symlink, see [Installing a local package on Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328000/installing-a-local-package-on-meteor)

For 3rd party modules from atmosphere, you simply `meteor add user:package` in the command line, or add `user:package` to the `.meteor/packages` file.

To use npm modules, you must use the `meteorhacks:npm` meteor package
https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm

Answer (score 1):

Well I think meteorjs comes with atmosphere where you can just do `meteor add <package name>`

You can find all supported packages here: https://atmospherejs.com